# scheduledend field on custom activity in CRM 2011 is being set to null on update

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

When I try to update a custom activity, the scheduledend date field is being set to null.

I'm using the generic Entity class to create and update the custom activity.

This occurs from a console application and a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be because I was also setting the scheduledstart date field during both create and update to `null`.

If I either drop the inclusion of the scheduledstart date field in Entity class when calling update, or set it to a value, the scheduledend date field update goes through just fine.

Another solution as pointed out in the comments would be to just use early-bound entity types generated by the Crm Service Util found in the SDK.

Comment: It's just the way the entity `Attributes` property works. Real solution: use early-bound classes, which implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which in turn produces the expected behavior.

Comment: @PeterMajeed Can you explain a bit more how using late-bound types causes the problem? From your comment I don't understand how adding two separate and distinct attributes to the entity could cause the problem. They're both nullable date fields so null should be ok to pass back -- in fact I'd assume that same would be sent when using strongly typed entity classes. I can try this out though.

Comment: Wow that is odd. Confirmed the issue does not happen when using strong types. In this scenario, we don't want to add the bloat from the strong types, but that's a valid solution I'll add to the answer although I still don't fully understand why the difference. Thanks!

Comment: When you generate the Xrm,cs file (if that's what you name it), do you generate classes for *all* entities, or just the entities you access in your project? Depending on how many and which entities you use, the Xrm file could potentially be smaller than 100 KB.

Comment: Regarding the late-bound types, I rarely/never use them, so I'm not the best source of info about them, but I believe that only the attributes in the `Attributes` property bag actually get passed to the database sever. I think you'd have to do something like `Attributes.Add("fieldname")` in order for the update to go through. Regardless, if you really wanted to know how it worked, the strongly typed classes use late-binding internally, so you can look in that file and see how it works.

Comment: @PeterMajeed The file that CrmSvcUtil generates we do trim down to be just the entities needed -- but there are potential for a lot of entities in this project. It's a consideration for sure though. How you mentioned adding attributes is exactly how we were adding attributes (which is how I do it in plugins, etc). So the update should've been going through fine. I may take a peek at the generated model sometime and see if I can't figure out what's happening in the late-bound types though... Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: What "bloat" are you talking about that your trying not to add by using the strong types?

Comment: @Daryl Just unnecessary overhead -- its very situation specific in this case.